# Ruby on Rails: belongs_to and has_many over the same pair on the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

First, my model definitions:

```
class Certificate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :certificate_series
end

class CertificateSeries < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :certificates
  belongs_to :last_certificate_in_series, :class_name => "Certificate", :foreign_key => :last_certificate_in_series_id
end
```

I thought of the association as: CertificateSeries have many Certificates and have a Certificate which is the last one in the series. I've thought of using have_one, but according to the [association basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_one-association), have_one is not correct based on where I put the associating key.

You can think of it as every time you get a new passport, the physical passport is changing (with its issuing and expiry date changing) but it is still a passport. Thus, you can have a lot of physical passports (certificates) but you only have 1 present passport (the last in the series, which is a physical passport) and the physical passports belong to the "passport" class of IDs (certificate series).

What I want is that I can call CertificateSeries.last_certificate_in_series and it will return the last certificate in the series. I thought of doing this in the db level by having the field last_certificate_in_series_id. I wanted to do it this way to reduce the database overhead of just getting the last one in the series. The other approach I thought of was get all the certificates in a series, arrange them by date, and get the most recent one.

Thus I'm now having problems trying to reflect this association in the models.

```
belongs_to :last_certificate_in_series, :class_name => "Certificate", :foreign_key => :last_certificate_in_series_id
```

seems not to define it properly. I can call CertificateSeries.last_certificate_in_series but it only returns a nilClass even when last_certificate_in_series_id is set to a valid value.

I'm open for suggestions on other approaches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a method that returns the last certificate in series.  You don't need to create another relationship for this.

```
class Certificate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :certificate_series
end

class CertificateSeries < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :certificates

  def last_certificate_in_series
    certificates.last
  end
end
```

Comment: Same as Peter Wong's solution, only implemented as a class method. As I see this, this will fetch all the certificates which belongs in a certificate series and then traverse the list, and return the last one. There will be an overhead fetch. For now, picking this answer for simplicity since I've kind of thought that I may be overoptimizing very early on in the project.

Comment: I don't have a way to check right now, but if I'm not mistaken, calling certificates.last should generate the query `SELECT * FROM certificates WHERE certificate_series_id = 1 ORDER BY id LIMIT 1` or something similar.  Of course the certificate_series_id would depend on the actual id of the series.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider the acts_as_list plugin.
Then in the certificate model:

```
belongs_to :certificate_series
acts_as_list :scope => certificate_series
```

Comment: Incidentally, I've thought of implementing my own list. Thanks, will check this plugin out.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need the extra `belongs_to` association. It sounds very natural that the last certificate in the `certificate_series.certificates` is the one you want. So you could simply do this:

```
class Certificate < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :certificate_series
end

class CertificateSeries < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :certificates
end

certificate_series.certificates.last
```

Comment: True, I've thought of this but then I've thought of performance concerns.

Comment: So when you retrieve a certificate_series from the database, you don't want all the certificates, but only the last one, right?